# How do I use Android device with USB OTG device as MTP client for another device?

Tags: root-access, file-transfer, mtp

I want this setup:

```
[My Android device, MTP client] --USB OTG-- [other Android device, MTP server]
```

For acting as MTP server, one simply chooses something like "Share files with computer running Windows or Mac".

How do I run MTP client for USB OTG connection?

Workaround:

1. Get root;
2. Setup Linux chroot
3. Download and build [AFT](https://github.com/whoozle/android-file-transfer-linux) insde the chroot
4. Use `aft-mtp-cli` or `aft-mtp-mount`.

I expect some proper application to use root access to talk to USB and act as MTP client for another device.

Comment: May I know the purpose of doing this? Is it just for File Transfer?

Comment: Yes, for managing files on another device. I want my smartphone to be able to do [almost] all things with USB OTG like a regular computer.

Comment: I have a solution, which requires atleast the other device (which you're gonna connect to the OTG enabled device) to be rooted.. Is that rooted? Or if you don't want to root it, the only way would be using apps that enable file transfer via WiFi Hotspot or WLAN, without OTG

Comment: With other device rooted I can just force mass storage mode.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I was about to say..